# How to add a prediction interval on a prediction vs observation plot?

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I am currently working on a regression prediction task using machine learning. As with most studies of this nature, I have been plotting prediction vs observation graphs to evaluate the predictive performance of my model. Ideally, the scatter points should concentrate around the line y=x.

However, I have come across several papers where the authors have incorporated a technique I am not familiar with. They have added prediction intervals to the graph, as shown in the attached image [from this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0039914021003520). I am intrigued by this approach and would like to understand how it is implemented.

Could anyone kindly explain how to add these prediction intervals to a prediction vs observation plot? Any guidance or references to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.
[image]